# How to call REST API and set to SAPUI5 model

Tags: sapui5

I am a beginner in developing SAPUI5 applications and am trying to make a drill down application with a flexible column layout. For my first page I am trying to grab country data from this api (https://www.api-basketball.com/documentation#section/Introduction). I have an API KEY through RapidAPI.

How would I go about grabbing the data and setting it to a model? I was able to print out the response in the console which gave me the data but I'm not sure how I can set this to the model and access the data so I can bind it to my controls in the XML view.
[screengrab of my console with response from the data]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1bnq.jpg

```
    onInit: function() {
                var myHeaders = new Headers();
                // I hid my actual API key with the x's
                myHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-key", "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx");
    
                var requestOptions = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: myHeaders,
                    redirect: 'follow'
                };        
                
                //set bball model
                var bBallModel = new JSONModel(
                    fetch("https://api-basketball.p.rapidapi.com/countries", requestOptions)
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(result =>  console.log(result))
                    .catch(error => console.log('error', error)));
                this.getView().setModel(bBallModel, "bball")
```

This is the code in my component.js file. Any help I would really appreciate thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to update the data after the call succeeds:

```
onInit: function() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    // I hid my actual API key with the x's
    myHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-key", "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx");

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    var model = new JSONModel();

    this.getView().setModel(model, "bball")

    //set bball model
        fetch("https://api-basketball.p.rapidapi.com/countries", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result =>  model.setData(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [`loadData`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel%23methods/loadData) method on the JSON model:

```
onInit: function() {
    var uri = "https://api-basketball.p.rapidapi.com/countries";
  var model = new JSONModel();
    var oHeaders = {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx"
    };
  
    this.getView().setModel(model, "bball")
    model.loadData(uri, null, true, "GET", null, false, oHeaders);
}
```

Comment: Why would you pass to JSONModel a promise? 
Why are you doing this in onInit in a controller? Do it in the component or in onRouteMatched.

Comment: @BenediktKromer The question is about onInit, and used as an example. The jsonmodel is *not* passed a promise, only populated in a promise. populating it in onRouteMatched will populate it every time the route is hit which is clearly wrong

Comment: I just noticed what you meant with ‘promise into the jsonmodel’ and fixed it

Comment: I ended up getting it to work. I used an Ajax call and also found out there was a syntax error with my binding in the xml. I tried the code you proposed above but I couldn't bind the result for some redone. the reposes I got from the Ajax call I was able to bind.

Comment: var that = this;
   var oView = that.getView();
   var settings = {
    "url": "https://api-basketball.p.rapidapi.com/countries",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx"
    },
     };
     $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    var bBallModel = new JSONModel(response.response);
    oView.setModel(bBallModel, 'bball');
    console.log(response.response);
    console.log(bBallModel);
     });